# How to Handle Error retrieving field value from bean : XXX exception in JasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports

My question is very simple :

How to handle this **exception in JasperReports** ?

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: 
Error retrieving field value from bean : XXX
```

Why I want this ?

If user forget to put/mis-spelled the field name in the jrxml, I dont want the execution to stop,
Instead I want some value to be replaced in this case like [No Field Found or No Data] in the expression.

I already tried

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
jasperReport.setProperty(JasperReport .PROPERTY_WHEN_NO_DATA_TYPE, "Yoooooo");
```

nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

Your bean method is not match with your field.
in jasper report you have one getter method for any field.
may be  Here your get method is not find or not available, 
check your getter method and put getXxx() method.

Comment: Thanks Maulik ... But I 'intentionally' want to catch the execption. Actually I am developing a package for report generation and if user miss something , I want to display no data rather than stopping the execution. I hope you get what I mean

Comment: create Your own user defined exception like data not found etc. if You are  missing some data then handle or Throw Exception with your own Error page.

In my application i'm using data missing exeption at missing any data for report.

Answer (score 0):

I got it man.

You have to create you own class for DataSource which extends the implementation of JRDataSource

and you have to override the method getFieldValue

So without further ado ... I bring to you .... the solution

```
public class CustomDataSource extends JRBeanCollectionDataSource {

    public CustomDataSource(Collection<?> beanCollection) {
        super(beanCollection);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getFieldValue(JRField field) throws JRException {
        try {
            Object returnVal = super.getFieldValue(field);
            return returnVal;
        } catch (JRException e) {
            // You can check for the type of exception like NoSuchMethod or BlaBlaBlackSheep
            return new String("[No Feild :" + field.getName() + "]");
        }

    }

}
```

and you Generation code will look like :

```
JRDataSource dataSource = new CustomDataSource((Collection<?>)data/*your DTO*/);
 JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, dataSource);
```

Thats It :)